# how do i pass selected text in chrome extension from background script to content script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a extension which is essentially a plagiarism checker. So, you copy the text and then right click after that you have are directed to our website. Now, what I want to do is that I want to send the selected text from my copied website to my website input page and then I want to click the submit button.
To do that I need to execute these two lines.

```
    document.getElementById("mycontent").value = "selected text";  
    document.getElementById("checkButton").click();
```

But the selected text remains in just background.js and never shows up in content script that's why my extension is not working. So, i want to know how can I fix this or is there any other way I can input my text and click the button.
Background.js

```
  var contextsList = ["selection"];

    for(i = 0;i<contextsList.length; i++){
        var context = contextsList[i];
        var titleX = " Check Plagiarism of Selected Text";
        chrome.contextMenus.create({title: titleX, contexts:[context], onclick: clickHandler, id: context });
    }
  function clickHandler(data, tab) {
         switch(data.menuItemId.id){
            case 'selection' :
             ex = encodeURIComponent(data.selectionText);
 var config = {content: ex};
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: 'var config = ' + JSON.stringify(config)
}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'contentScript.js'});
});
// background script
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendMessage)=>{

if(request.type==="Getcontent"){
    const  content=// set your content 
    sendMessage({msg:"cont",content:content})

}

})

chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://greatseotools.net/plagiarism-checker"});


   break;

            }

         }
```

ContentScript.js

```
        //Content script 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendMessage)=>{

    if(request==='content'){
     console.log("content",request.content)       
    }

})

//wrap this in an event 
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type:'Getcontent'
})
```

manifest.json

```
    {
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/19.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["contentScript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://*.greatseotools.net/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
   "description": "Check Plagiarism by just selecting text..",
   "homepage_url": "https://www.prepostseo.com/plagiarism-checker",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icons/128.png",
      "16": "icons/16.png",
      "48": "icons/48.png"
   },
    "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Plagiarism Checker for Chrome",
   "permissions": [ "activeTab","*://*/*", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/", "contextMenus" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

Website on which I have to input text and click the button.

```
https://greatseotools.net/plagiarism-checker
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line `chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'contentScript.js'})` you didn't pass your selectionText to the content script you can acheive that in many ways here are two of my suggestions :

**background script**

**1. Using the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` api**

```
 ex = encodeURIComponent(data.selectionText);
 var config = {content: ex};
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: 'var config = ' + JSON.stringify(config)
}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'content.js'});
});
```

**content script**

and in your content script you should be able to retrieve ex :

```
alert('mycontent:' + config);
```

**2. Using the chrome messages api between backgound and content script**

**background script**

```
  // background script
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendMessage)=>{

if(request.type==="Getcontent"){
    const  content=// set your content 
    sendMessage({msg:"cont",content:content})

}

})
```

**Content script**

```
//Content script 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendMessage)=>{

    if(request==='content'){
     console.log("content",request.content)       
    }

})

//wrap this in an event 
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type:'Getcontent'
})
```

**3.use chrome storage**

**background script**

```
 chrome.storage.sync.set({'content':ex})
```

**content script**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['content'], function(res) {
      console.log('Value currently is ' + res.content);
    });
```

**manifest**

```
"permissions": ["storage"]
```

Comment: can you please tell where should i put this code i mean which code should i put in background.js and which should i put in contentscript.js

Comment: i have adjusted the answer let me know if it worked

Comment: nothing is happening i have edited my question and this is how i pasted your code. If you think something is wrong you can tell me. Also, you can edit your answer again with full code so that i can use it.

Comment: you are trying to use both approaches, try first the first one and see if it works for you use only the code under 1. Using the chrome.tabs.executeScript api

Comment: I have used both code seperately but nothing happens code executes without error but there is nothing in console log and in the alert code it is saying config is not defined. Also, after adding id it just stops executing the code inside. I am going to add manifest to questing so that you can check for any error

Comment: remove the id and use it as before `data.menuItemId`  add this in your manifest to your background `"persistent":false` also change the even from `onclick` to `onclicked`

Comment: i have added a simpler way to pass data to content scrip check the third aproach

Comment: sync is not defined it is saying and if i change onclick to onlclicked it just doesn't run

Comment: Can you just tell me how can I insert in my website textarea some selected text that is what i need to make a chrome extension for

Comment: in the documentation the event is `onclicked` `chrome.contextMenus.onclicked.addListener` also for the chrome storage to work you have to add it in the permissions in manifest, have you done that?

Comment: `"permissions": ["storage"] ` add this to you manifest in permissions